# Centered Vertical Radial Buttons

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

[image]

http://liveweave.com/73vub5

So I got the objects to display the way I want as seen in the image, but my problem now is when I choose the second object the first should become unchecked and choose the second one. Using regular input boxed just inside a form it does it automatically without the need for JavaScript. Anyway to fix this that'll same me tons of time coding so I don't have to define it in Javascript/JQuery each time an object has been selected/checked and deselected/unchecked.

```
<style type="text/css">
div#container div {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:1.25%;}

div#circle {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px dashed #000;
    border-radius:50%;}

div#square {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px dashed #000;}
</style>

<div id="container" align="center">
    <form>
        <div id="square"><br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="squareselec" checked="true"></div>

        <div id="circle"><br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="circleselec"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the input element, you'll need to make the radio display: inline-block; - and it's container text-align: center;

I sugest staying away from id's unless using them for javaScript hooks or very special reasons. [HERE is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spxcn/) with the code for you to play with. I hope this helps. -nouveau

HTML

```
<div class="object-wrapper">
    <img alt="image name" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <input type="radio" name="squareselec" />
</div>

<div class="object-wrapper">
    <img alt="image name"  class="circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <input type="radio" name="squareselec" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.object-wrapper {
    width: 3em; /* arbitrary */

    text-align: center;

    /* to explain visually */
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: .1em;

    /* to grid them */
    float: left;
    margin-right: .5em;
}

.object-wrapper img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.object-wrapper input[type="radio"] {
    display: inline-block;

}

.circle { /* to make a circle */
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sure thing. We happen to be dealing with radio buttons this week at nouveau.